# Dlls and updating them (c#) (client/server)

Tags: c#, dll, client

I am a software engineer, I work in c# development.

The software I am working on has a server and client layout. The server is more of a Database Layer, only it has direct 'access' to the Database. The client simply sends requests and receives the data in form of strings according to the requests, and not data sets or data tables. The database layer interacts with the database thru a dll file.

example:

Client requests that operation 144 is to be executed. 
Server receives the operation number, sends it to the dll main routine:

```
Client:
    string command = "144";
    buffer = asci.GetBytes(command);
    socket.send(buffer);

Server:
    socket.receive(buffer);
    str = asci.GetString(buffer);
    op = Int32.Parse(str);
    Dll.MainRoutine(op);

Dll main routine:
    switch (op) 
    {
       case 0: blah blah blah ; break;
       case ..........................
       case 144: i++ ; break ;
       default : ;
    }
```

Lets say the software is running on the actual server. I now want to introduce changes to the client and dll file only (add functionality). Yet I do not want to compile the server again. If I add a new command on the client side called 200, and I add a case to the dll main routine: case 200, will it work? Or do I need to recompile the sever as well?

```
Client:
    string command = "200";
    buffer = asci.GetBytes(command);
    socket.send(buffer);

Server:
    socket.receive(buffer);
    str = asci.GetString(buffer);
    op = Int32.Parse(str);
    Dll.MainRoutine(op);

Dll main routine:
    switch (op) 
    {
       case 0: blah blah blah ; break;
       case ..........................
       case 144: i++ ; break ;
       case 200: i+=10 ; break ;
       default : ;
    }
```

What I am trying to say is I want to be able to add functionality thru updates to the dll and client only. The server must always be running. Can this be done with dlls or is there another way?

Thank you...

Comment: As an aside -- in this day of WCF and webservices, why did you choose to implement it this way?

Comment: The client and server will be in the same office. But on different machines. The employees will not have access to the server, just the clients. And I need to control the number of accesses to the server, and who access' it. I will look into WFC, as for webservice, I doubt that will be even possible due to the fact that this software will be built for accountants, which involves a lot of data going back and fourth. So in terms of efficiency and speed, I am not sure a webservice will cut it. But I can be wrong. I still did not build anything. I am simply in the design phase.

Comment: You are wrong about the efficiency and speed. WCF is an up-to-date technology and should be used instead of a home grown protocol.

Comment: I see two votes for WFC, I will look into it. Thank you. Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to recompile the server if it just passes the command number to the DLL. It is completely sufficient to just re-compile the DLL and deploy it on the server.